# Docker image error: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Im running this dockerfile and I get: ERROR Run python -m playwright install
`/bin/sh python: not found`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install TikTokApi
RUN python -m playwright install // Results in error
```

Comment: What "2015 question" are you talking about? If you are asking a question because an existing question did not solve the problem, please include a link, and *explain exactly why and how* your question is different.

Comment: This is totally different from that question (which used Unicode quotes an a JSON-format `CMD`) and I've removed the references to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a [Playwright image with Python](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/playwright/python/about) instead of the [Playwright image with Node](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/playwright/about) you have currently set,

do

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.23.0-focal
```

instead. You won't then need to install `python3-pip` (or playwright!) at all.

Additionally, you'll probably want to explicitly spell out `python3` instead of `python`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.23.0-focal
RUN pip3 install TikTokApi
RUN playwright install
COPY . .
```

Comment: Hello, I just updated the above to reflect your change, but now I get a different error  => ERROR [1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:focal@sh  219.2s,     and the additional log: failed to add snapshot qqlouq3e6fv0n349spyjlf7e8 to lease: input/output error

Comment: Currently in the middle of testing...

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal of vscode, type `sudo apt install python-is-python3` then restart, it should work.

Comment: But shouldn't a docker image create its dependencies perfectly the same regardless of which system is starting the image?

Comment: It should and it does. The binary is called python3.